# Difference between two tables

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have two tables like this:

```
Table1:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem
OI1
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI6
];

Table2:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI5
OI6
];
```

Now I want a third table which shows me that **only** OI5 is not in "Table1"!
 A Listbox solution is also ok.

I tried some things with joins bit it didn't work. I also read [this](https://community.qlik.com/thread/32944) 
but it only showed me the difference between the two tables in a listbox. See below:

```
Table1:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem
OI1
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI6
];

Concatenate(Table1)
Table2:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI5
OI6
];

INNER JOIN (Table1)
LOAD *
WHERE "Only in One Table?"
;

// Here I want "OI5" as an output
Difference:
LOAD 
    OrderItem,
    if(count(OrderItem)<2,-1) as "Only in One Table?"   
RESIDENT Table1 GROUP BY OrderItem
;
```

Result:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
Table1:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem1
OI1
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI6
];

Table2:
LOAD * INLINE [
OrderItem2
OI2
OI3
OI4
OI5
OI6
];

Missings:
Load 
    OrderItem2 as MissingsOrderItem
Resident 
    Table2
Where
    Not Exists(OrderItem1, OrderItem2)  
;
```

After reload the result will be:

[image]

Comment: Thanks good answer but I just need to show only OI5 in the listbox "MissingsOrderItem".

Answer (score -1):

Select LOAD * from Table 2 where LOAD not in (Select LOAD from Table 1);

Comment: I have no ODBC-connection! Just two tables in the script.

Comment: Simulate the inner query using nested for loop.

Comment: Can you show me how you would do it? Sounds interesting ^^